# How to create dynamic link between list variables

Tags: python

The dictionary's methods `.viewvalues()` and `.viewkeys()` allow to create the list variables that will be linked and dynamically updated on every dictionary modification such as:

```
diction={'one':1,'two':2,'three':3}
dict_values=dictVar.viewvalues()
dict_keys=dictVar.viewkeys()
```

I wonder if a similar functionality could be achieved with lists. So if there are two "source" list variables and a third list is a result of sums of twos:

```
a=[1,2,3]
b=[4,5,6]
sum=a+b
```

Now what i want is a list variable `sum` to get updated if/when list variable `a` or list variable `b` is modified. How to achieve that?

Comment: I'm not sure you can do exactly what you're trying to do. `sum=a+b` creates an entirely new list that is not inherently linked to either `a` or `b`, so I don't think a single variable can do what you're trying to do. You may prefer to just call a function that returns `a+b` whenever you want `sum`.

Comment: `sum` is just a regular list variable here of course. I used it here to illustrate the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd define a function to do it and then call that whenever you need the list.

```
a=[1,2,3]
b=[4,5,6]

def sum(a, b):
    return a + b
```

Then, in an interpreter:

```
>>> sum(a, b)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> a.append(5)
>>> sum(a, b)
[1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 5, 6]
```

If it's not necessary that it be a flat list, you can easily do what you'd want.

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = [4, 5, 6]
>>> sum = [a, b]
>>> print(sum)
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> a.append(8)
>>> print(sum)
[[1, 2, 3, 8], [4, 5, 6]]
```

That said, I'd recommend against defining a variable named `sum` as it's a [built-in Python function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum).

Comment: Yes, but then you would have to always add an extra line every time the list variable was modified... such as `a.append(7); varaibleToKeppUpdated=sum(a,b)` I was looking for an automated way. So you update variable `a` and `varaibleToKeppUpdated` gets updated "all by itself".

Comment: I added an update for if you'd like to do it as nested lists.

Comment: list of lists seems to be a good way around it. I think I can stick to it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could do it the other way around, using `numpy` arrays.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> ab = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
>>> a = ab[:3]
>>> b = ab[3:]
>>> a, b
(array([1, 2, 3]), array([4, 5, 6]))
>>> a[1] = 9
>>> ab
array([1, 9, 3, 4, 5, 6])
>>> ab[0] = 7
>>> a
array([7, 9, 3])
```

Here, `a` and `b` are "views" on the array `ab`, and modifying one will also modify the other.

Starting with `a` and `b`, just create a numpy array from `a+b` and redefine `a` and `b` accordingly:

```
>>> a, b = [1,2,3], [4,5,6]
>>> ab = np.array(a+b)
>>> a, b = ab[:3], ab[3:]
```

Comment: I don't know why they down vote. It drives me crazy when they do it.

Comment: I don't get it. `a` and `b` are "source" or "master" variables from which variable `sum` is built of and which is supposed to be dynamically linked to `a` and `b`. Please show how to do that. In your example I can't see the variable 'sum'

Comment: @Sputnix Im my example, `sum` is renamed to `ab`, mainly because `sum` is already the name of a builtin function.

Comment: `a,b=[1,2,3],[4,5,6];c=np.array(a+b);a.append(7);print c` --> `c` prints a sum of `a+b` lists before `a` was appended 7

Comment: @Sputnix You also have to make `a` a view of `c`, like `a` = c[:len(a)]`. However, while this works fine for changing values in `a` or `b`, I'm afraid that it does not work for extending `a` or `b`. In this case, I guess you should go with the nested list...

Answer (score 0):

You will have to right a custom data structure to do this.  Here is something in the right direction...

```
class LinkedArrays(object):
    def __init__(self, sourceArray1, sourceArray2, combineFunction):
        self.sa1, self.sa2 = sourceArray1, sourceArray2

        self.__combineFunction = combineFunction
        self.__update()

    def updateSourceArray1(self, index, value):
        self.sa1[index] = value
        self.__update()

    def updateSourceArray2(self, index, value):
        self.sa2[index] = value
        self.__update()

    def __update(self):
        self.combinedArray = [self.__combineFunction(self.sa1[i], self.sa2[i]) for i in range(len(self.sa1))]

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self.combinedArray[item]


summedArrays = LinkedArrays([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], lambda x, y: x+y)
print summedArrays[0]  # print 5

summedArrays.updateSourceArray1(0, 6)
print summedArrays[0]  # print 10
```